# Rails 4.x before_action with params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am trying to make my rails code a bit nicer.

I have this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
    # @variable_defined_else_where is an object w/ accessors
    @variable_defined_else_where.some_value = "string"
  end
end
```

I would like to do this some how get to here:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  variable_defined_else_where(some_value: "string")
  # or
  variable_defined_else_where.some_value = "string"
  # or
  some_method "string"
end
```

I looked at the rails actionview code, for "layout" which has a similar syntax-ness

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout "string"
end
```

However, it declares a method in the class, I need to modify a

```
 @variable_defined_else_where
```

which then controls how several bits of helpers behave

```
module MyHelper
  def do_if_that
    if @variable_defined_else_where == "string"
      # do so and so
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get to syntaxically happy-ness?

Answer (score 1):

Since `before_action` executes in the instance context, your variable-in-question is an instance variable, which means it's only set on the *instance* of the controller (i.e., during the request lifecycle). On the other hand, `layout` is most likely setting a property on the controller class itself.

If your variable could be moved to the class-level without compromising thread-safety, you could make it a class attribute and set it directly like:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  @@my_variable = 3

  def test
    @@my_variable   # returns 3
  end
end
```

But if you don't like how `@` signs look, maybe that's not better :)

Here's another option, which just wraps your before_action definition inside a class method:

```
module SetsSomeVariable
  include ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def set_variable(value)
      self.before_action do
        @my_variable = value
      end
    end
  end
end

# ...

class MyController < ApplicationController
  include SetsSomeVariable  # this could be in ApplicationController

  set_variable 'string'
end
```

Comment: Don't use controller class variables for anything dependent on the current request. Its just a huge antipattern.

Comment: I tried class variables, I got some "wierd" behavior from it.  I think it has to do with the load order and inhereitance, but since it didn't work as expected, I moved on.